# Ubuntu 12.04 can't use mouse and internet

Tags: boot, graphics, mouse, internet, system

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 for a while on my Acer Aspire One-722. It was ok, but then, after some updates, the next time i started it, an window "the system is running in low-graphics mode" appeared. I couldn't find out, what to do, so i reinstalled Ubuntu from DVD. The installation went normally, but when i rebooted, I saw it doesn't react on mouse moving, only to keyboard. It also doesn't connect to wi-fi (or i just don't know, how to connect to it without mouse). I tried to find an answer in the internet, but most of advises include downloading something, which I can't do.
Thanks everyone who would try to help me.

graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6250 Graphics

network: Atheros AR8152/8158 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)

processor: AMD C-50

Comment: Problem solved - just rteinstall with deleting all files. Didn't want to lose everything, but, after all, now I have Ubuntu working normally.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question to askubuntu. It would be best for those who experience the same thing in the future if you would add an answer detailing what you did to fix this, and then accept your own answer. Answering and accepting your own answer is encouraged on askubuntu if you have found the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer only for graphic issue**

## AMD ATI Catalyst 12.6 Installation

Remove the old AMD driver with these commands:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh 

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

Then start the installation of AMD Catalyst 12.6 with these commands:

```
cd /tmp && wget -O amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run

chmod +x amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run 

sudo sh amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run
```

Follow instructions and run this command:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Reboot you PC

## Upgrade from AMD Catalyst 12.* to 12.9

```
cd /tmp && wget -O amd-driver-installer-9.00-x86.x86_64.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/embedded/9.00-120815a-146426C-EDG_Direct.zip
```

Make the package executable

```
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-9.00-x86.x86_64.run
```

Create deb packages

```
sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-9.00-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

Force overwrite the older packages with the new ones

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i *.deb
```

Reboot you PC

If want to unistall them

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Enjoy!

Comment: first two commands didn't work: seems like I don't have this driver at all.
Third didn't work either: it can't connect to the site cause i can't access internet...

Comment: if not, proceed to download and installation process ;)

Comment: Anyway, thank you. Seems like I have to connect to internes somehow...

Comment: No problem. Yes you need internet connection. Enjoy Ubuntu!